# CAN bus bi-directional communication implementation: Should I be always listening, and use interrupt for sending?

Tags: can-bus

I've been playing around with a couple Arduinos and some CAN bus receiver/transmitters. Right now, I've only set it up for one to send and one to receive.

I'm starting to work on bi-directional communication, but I'm wondering how it is typically set up.

My thinking was to have each node always listen for messages, and when a node wants to send a message, I would use an interrupt. This works great for things like buttons, and I would use timer interrupts for the rest.

Is this a good way to do it or is there a better/proper way?

Comment: No, there isn't.  There is only the way that most effectively meets your specific requirements.

Comment: The proper way is to send messages as enforced by your application layer protocol. As for how to properly design a CAN application protocol, that's a big topic.